# jQuery.validate / metadata... combining to validation

Tags: jquery

Hi i'm trying to combine the following two jquery.validate codes... they both work fine separately. I tried just adding `$.metadata.setType('attr', 'validate');` before the doc ready on the second script, that didn't work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$.metadata.setType('attr', 'validate');
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#reg_form").validate();
});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var validator = $("#reg_form").validate({
            errorLabelContainer: $("#reg_form div.error"),
            meta: "validate"
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#reg_form").metadata.setType('attr', 'validate');
   //or
   $.metadata.setType('attr', 'validate');
```

Comment: i tried both of those prior to posting. I need to combine the first statement into the second. when ever I added metadata... into it stops processing everything else